# Google OAuth unauthorized_client mobile and web app

Tags: ios, google-api

We have 1 google app with 2 separate sets of credentials.

One for a web app, the other for an iOS app.

We're trying to have users authenticate on mobile and send the "code" parameter to our api where we turn that into an access_token and refresh_token(for use with background processing). The issue that we're getting is "unauthorized_client".

We've been following the portion for "enable server-side api access for your app" https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

The api is using the same credentials as the iOS app for these type of exchanges.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the exact same issue now too.